# stack on insert or update sql table on a user

Tags: java, sql

Hello i am trying to create a program that has users and each user can calculate his payment due to his pay per hour value and how many hours he has worked.

I am stacked on the button which adds hours to a specific user or updates

usernameGL --> global variable (public static String usernameGL ="";)
Connect() --> method (workes!)

i am using Access DB and java

```
    private void addBT_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double hours1 = 0.0;
    double hoursTable = 0.0;

    hours1 =
            Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "How many hours did u work?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));

    //establish connection
    Connect();

    try {
        ResultSet result;
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        String SQL = "SELECT Att.hours FROM Att WHERE Att.ID = users1.ID AND users1.username='" + usernameGL + "'";
        result = state.executeQuery(SQL);

        if (result.next()) {
            hoursTable = result.getDouble("hours");
            if (hoursTable == 0) {
                SQL = "INSERT INTO Att (hours) VALUES (" + hours1+")";
                result = state.executeQuery(SQL);

                String hoursString = toString().valueOf(hoursTable);
                currentTF.setText(hoursString);

            } else if (hoursTable > 0) {
                double total = hoursTable + hours1;
                SQL = "UPDATE Att SET hours= (" + total + ") WHERE hours = (" + hoursTable+")";

                String hoursString = toString().valueOf(total);
                currentTF.setText(hoursString);
            }

        }


    } catch (SQLException f) {
    }
}
```

Comment: i am new to the forum if something is inappropriate tell me to change it instanly thnx

Comment: @topillo . . . Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question doesn't seem to have a question in it.  What is the issue?

Comment: when i execute my program and i add hours to a specific user dosent do anything either to the texfield or to the databse